# Getting git to never push a single commit?

Tags: git

I don't think this is possible, but thought someone might have a nifty idea of how to accomplish this:

I have a project that I checked out that was in existence long before I took it over.  I have about a dozen changes in various files that I never want checked in (they're all config changes).

Is there any way to commit this set of changes and then never actually push that one commit?  I know it sounds odd :)

clarification:

I want these changes to stay in my working directory, I need them for the app to function locally.  I want to be able to keep commit other changes around them, even changes in the same file, but never push the config changes to anywhere else...

It's somewhat like before every push I would want to:

- cherry pick and stash this one commit
- rebase the one commit out
- push
- re-apply this stash to my codebase

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a similar pattern to maintaining a local patch set to an upstream project you don't control.  The easiest way to handle this is to have an intermediate branch that all changes get merged through, like this:

```
___________________________ master
\__________________________ config-changes
     \_____________________ daily-work
```

`master` contains everything that is to be shared.  The only things committed in `config-changes` are changes you want to be able to revert easily when they are shared.  `daily-work` is the branch you do all your work in.  To set it up, do:

```
# (no local config changes should be in master at this point)
git checkout -b config-changes master
# Make your config-related changes that you don't want to share
git commit -am "Made local config changes"
git checkout -b daily-work
# Work and commit like normal
```

When you're ready to share your changes, do:

```
git rebase --onto master config-changes daily-work
git checkout master
git merge daily-work
```

That will revert all the changes made in `config-changes`, but otherwise make it look like you branched directly from `master`.  Note that after you do this rebase, if you want to continue to work in `daily-work`, you need to rebase it back onto `config-changes`, but it's really better to create a new branch for each change.

When you need to pull down new changes from `master`, do:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout config-changes
git merge master
```

The merge reapplies your local config changes onto the latest master.  You're then free to create a new `daily-work` branch, or merge `config-changes` into the old one, as appropriate.  Basically, you never merge directly from `master` into `daily-work`.  You always go through `config-changes` first.

It seems like a lot of work at first, but once you do it once or twice you'll see it's a lot easier than maintaining the changes manually.

Comment: SmartGit have a feature called "Interactive Rebase" which lets you easily move commits up and down.  For this case, moving up the "config-changes" commit to top-most is easy in the dialog.  Then, just push at the commit just before "config-changes".  As a preventive measure to avoid accidentally pushing in my temp commits, I add a "TMP:" prefix in the commit message, and then added a local push-hook to warn me when I accidentally push my temp commits.

Comment: Having said that, I'm getting tired of doing this.  Is there an easier way to automate this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) on these files to make git think that the files are not modified.

After comments, an alternative is to have a separate branch that you push from. The commits in this branch are cherry picked etc from the work branch. So when you want to push, switch to the "push" branch, cherry-pick commits from "work" and push.

Comment: If I'm reading the docs on that correctly, this is akin to a `git ignore`?

Comment: @cwolves - This is for "ignoring" changes to files that are already tracked. `git ignore` is for ignoring files out of the repo.

Comment: ahh, gotcha.  Thanks, but not quite what I need - I need to be able to later commit to that one file, but not the changes I previously made...  I'm working on a project where the "config" is scattered amongst a dozen files that I also need to later modify.  Ideally I'd consolidate all this into one/a couple config files, but it's so tied into everything that it would take half a day to do...

Comment: @cwolves - Then you really should look at changing the structure of your project.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, just create a separate branch and store these changes there:

```
git checkout -b your-new-branch
git commit -a
```

After you are done committing, just go back to your original branch and forget about these changes.

Comment: I would think he wants the changes in the branch he is working on now. Going back would remove the changes.

Comment: I want the changes in my local codebase.  i.e. I want them all in my working directory, I just don't ever want them to get pushed anywhere.  If I do this in a branch, I don't see how I would ever have access to both these changes and the ones I do want pushed.

Comment: Possibly that's the case. I will wait for cwolves to clarify.

Comment: Well, as @manojlds pointed out, `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is one option. It breaks down though when you have a file where you want to commit one set of changes but leave another as it is. Could you not move all these config related lines into one single file?

Comment: this is not what the user wants. the user wants to work on the changes with his changes to the development branch committed but doesn't want those initial development branch commits to be added to the main branch

Comment: I feel like this user @ChaitanyaGupta is revenge down voting. Will need to report him to the community.